# Realtime graph in D3.js and javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a question and I know it might be silly!
I have a Json file and I want to create a dynamic graph with javascript and D3.js in which x axis updated with the time and on y axis we have the values coming from the value field of json file. As you can see the time in this file is past so I want to have the current time of the system when the value is read, so I always have the updated time not the past time of this json file.

```
"values": [
        {
            "time": 124123213,
            "value": 500
        },
        {
            "time": 124123214,
            "value": 600
        },
]
```

My question is that how is it possible to have a DYNAMIC graph based on this json file. Since the values in this json file is limited and when it ends the graph stands still. Is it any way to generate it dynamically to make the graph updates forever?  Should I do any ajax or any extra thing? Does anyone know any similar example in javascript and D3.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think this will help you out. http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `setInterval(function(){},time)` function. It's part of javaScript core and will execute whatever function it's given every `time` milliseconds. You can use this function to make an AJAX request, probably using the `d3.json(url[, callback])` method, in which you'll specify the URL for your updated data, and then run a callback function on that data that will create or update elements based on the new data as required.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the JavaScript code to periodically make AJAX requests to get the latest JSON data. Then you can update your graph accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of doing the same thing. you can look at my code from here;

[Drawing multiple real time lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769463/drawing-multiple-real-time-lines)

However, I need to work on plotting multiple lines on the same plane.